# Class Object seen as Undefined when Event Binding after Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

First post, woo! Looked around quite a bit, but couldn't find a solution. Thanks for your attention and time. I have a class instance here with an array which I populate with objects from JSON data based on an ajax call. I would like to bind a function which renders the array as HTML, to an HTML button element.

Using when() after the instantiation and ajax call is complete, I can call upon properties of the instance, and even execute the function. But when I attempt to bind that same function to an HTML button click event, when I fire the event, the function references to an undefined 'theStats' object.

```
$(function () 
{
// Main Stats Object
var theStats = new Stats();
var initPop = theStats.populate();

$.when(initPop).done(function(a1)
{
    // Returns defined instance property
    console.log(theStats.arr.length);
    // Function works properly 
    theStats.render();

    // Why does this bind to an undefined 'theStats', when it executed
    // only when the ajax call, as well as object construction is complete?
    $("#render-stats").on("click", theStats.render);
});
});
```

I believe it is my misunderstanding about how asynchronous works? I was looking into event delegation as well, however I'm not creating a new HTML element, but an Object based on ajax. Any and all feedback is much appreciated (including my code practices, heh). Please let me know if I missed a similar solution, or if I've misunderstood how to stackoverflow. Thanks again!

```
 class Stats 
   {

constructor()
{
    // Creates Array for Stat Objects
    this.arr = [];  
}

/* Populate method requests thru ajax the JSON on the server on execution and 
    populates this current Stats object's array 
*/
populate()
{
    var that = this;
    var ajaxGet = $.get("php/get.php",
    function(jsonData, status)
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        for (let key in obj)
        {
            var newStat = new Stat(obj[key].id, obj[key].distance, obj[key].date);
            that.arr.push(newStat);
        } 
        this.arr = that.arr;
        console.log("Ajax Complete: " + this.arr);
    });
    return ajaxGet;
}


/* Render method creates HTML elements and renders them to the page using the data currently stored 
    within this particular Stats object */
render()
{
    $("#test").text("");

    for (let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++)
    {
        $("#test").append("<li class='runStat'> Run Number: " + this.arr[i].id + ", Distance: " + this.arr[i].distance + ", on Date: " + this.arr[i].date + "</li> <br/>");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you need to know how `this` works ... you could `$("#render-stats").on("click", theStats.render.bind(theStats))` as a simple fix ... or `$("#render-stats").on("click", function(){theStats.render();});`

Comment: woah well thanks that just unhitched me bigtime. much appreciated! could you explain what i did wrong with "this"? if not thanks anyway!